# How to write an or statement in mongodb using the find function in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to check if there is a booking in a range of time. Not sure how to use the or condition in mongodb using mongoose.

Here is what I have:

```
const appoinments = await Appointment.find({
      seller: seller._id,
      startTime: {
        $gt: ISODate(new Date(req.body.startTime).toISOString),
        $lt: ISODate(new Date(req.body.endTime).toISOString),
      },// I WANT TO ADD THE OR TO THIS TWO QUERIES
      endTime: {
        $gt: ISODate(new Date(req.body.startTime).toISOString),
        $lt: ISODate(new Date(req.body.endTime).toISOString),
      },
    });
```

I want to check and find for any appointment that conflict with new appointment that is about to be added or any appointment that ends during that time of the appointment.

Here is what my Appointment looks like:

```
 const appointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    seller: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Seller",
     },
    startTime: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
      },
    endTime: {
        type: Date,
      },
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `or()` member function that mongoose provides. It works just like the `$or` operator defined in the mongoose [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

I hope it helped!

```
const appoinments = await Appointment.find().or([
    {
        startTime: {
            $gt: ISODate(new Date(req.body.startTime).toISOString),
            $lt: ISODate(new Date(req.body.endTime).toISOString),
        }
    },
    {
        endTime: {
            $gt: ISODate(new Date(req.body.startTime).toISOString),
            $lt: ISODate(new Date(req.body.endTime).toISOString),
        },
    }
]);
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks a lot! Is it possible to also add .and() to this? Ex. Appointment.find().and().or()    ?

Comment: Yeah you can :)
If you are going to use multiple like "and()" & "or()", I would use the direct mongo operators ($or, $and), as I personally find it more readable.
[Link to documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand what you are saying as I was trying it out and it is confusing (to read) when using the function instead of the operators.

Comment: Yeah I totally get that. I'm glad you figured it out in the end though! Mongoose can be confusing at first glance, but trust me it gets a lot easier as time goes :-)